# I am trying to access the video from the Document directory and i am getting error "No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have downloaded the video in document directory. I have double check it is exist in same directory. but getting error "No such file or directory". Please help me.

I have gone through all available answer from SO. but not found the answer.

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

var toURL = NSURL(string: "file:/\(documentsPath)")!

toURL = toURL.appendingPathComponent("1VIDEO.MOV")! as NSURL

var strPath = ""

print(toURL)

do {
        strPath = try String(contentsOf: toURL as URL)           
        print(strPath)
   }

catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
   }
```

I should get the local file path in string format. i should be able to access it and able to play the video in avplayer.

Comment: Thank you mag_zbc for editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to create the URL is cumbersome and outdated. The error occurs because a slash in the URL is missing (the scheme is `file://`). Never create file system URLs with `URL(string` anyway. And don't use `NSURL` in Swift.

Please use the FileManager API. And you cannot read video data as `String`

```
do {
    let documentsURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let toURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("1VIDEO.MOV")
    let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: toURL)
    print(videoData)
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are converting it into data but i want to pass it as string to avplayer. I understand your point but i don't know how to use the data with AVPlayer.

Comment: That's impossible. You can pass the URL to `AVPlayer` [directly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385706-init)

Comment: vadian still i am facing same issue. "The file “1VIDEO.MOV” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file"

Comment: Is `1VIDEO.MOV` spelled correctly? Case sensitivity matters. Does the file really exist?

Comment: yes buddy. I have checked it. it is exist in the same location.